# implemented SQLExtendedFetch function in my odbc driver(3.5) ,but odbc driver manager still says drivers doesn't support this function

Tags: database, windows, odbc, driver

as the title says , I have implemented this deprecated function for some odbc 2.0 applications ,when one application start to connect a database via this odbc driver , shows the below error message

I have implemented SQLGetFunctions also ,so this deprecated API could be noted as already implemented.

I am really confused ,any help will be appreciated ,thanks a lot!

[image: this is the error msg:]

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question .
The reason is odbc driver on windows is dll.So I need to export the api either by declspec(dllexport) or by dll_name.def file . I don't add the the API name to the def file,so driver manager panics.(I just developed the project halfway ,and not aware of  the def file)

It is dumb ,indeed .But maybe it can help some novice like me ,who are not familiar with dll mechanism